# New to Python, can someone please explain why these two pieces of code output a different result?

Tags: python

As title says, I'm new to Python (started using Python3 about 4 days ago). I'm having a hard time understanding why these two seemingly equivalent pieces of code give a different result.

I've been recommended to try my hand at some of the problems on projecteuler, to me these two look like they should output the same number. I assume it's something small that i'm not noticing. Thanks in advance.

My code outputs: 266333
Other code outputs: 233168

```
#my code
sum3 = sum({*range(3, 1000, 3)})
sum5 = sum({*range(5, 1000, 5)})
print(sum3 + sum5)

#someone else's solution
print(sum({*range(3, 1000, 3)} | {*range(5, 1000, 5)}))
```

Comment: Why are they "seemingly identical"? To me they are different. One uses `+` and the other uses `|`. And one uses `sum` twice and the other uses `sum` once.

Comment: @mkrieger1 i see now with the ```+``` and ```|``` but why would the use of ```sum``` twice change the result? I've adjusted my code and tried again and the result is still different... again very new so this is a little confusing

Comment: This is really just a math question: the sets overlap. Split the sets into their overlapping and non overlapping parts, and you'll see why the sums are different.

Comment: Because of 15 and the like. Some numbers are multiples of 3, some are multiples of 5, and some are multiples of both...

Comment: Imagine you replaced your 1000 with 16, so the calcs are small enough to do with pen and paper.  What would you expect the results to be then?

Comment: Try to understand this syntax - `s3 = {*range(3, 1000, 3)}`   type(s3) ---> set

Comment: It's a *huge* difference - if you dissect these two ways step-by-step.  All the comments are really point put out the key difference.

Comment: Okay, I understand now. Thank you all for the replies it's been a huge help, I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. Note well that this is **not a discussion forum**, and that you [are expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to attempt your own analysis of the problem first - not to "show effort", but so that you can ask a *specific* question that allows us to address whatever is the *actual point of confusion* (assuming there still is one).

Answer (score 0):

The second approach will eliminate duplicates while merging, but the first one will not.
Hence the difference in the sum.

Answer (score 0):

Lets thake 15 as an example.
If you use the first approach 15(3*5) will appear both in the summation of the first array and the second array.
In the second approach 15 will appear just one time!
enche the difference in the sum.

Answer (score 0):

In your code part you get a sum of two different sets and then you summarize them. sum3 - sum of first set, sum5 - sum of second set and then you have a print of sum this two sums.

In someone else's solution at first you got two sets and then they are merged and then you have a sum of set of two merged sets.

Answer (score 0):

range(3, 1000, 3) give you all multiple of 3, and range(5, 1000, 5) the multiple of 5, I hope that is clear at least, and notice that a number can be both like 15.

so when you sum them separately you get a bigger number

```
sum3 = sum({*range(3, 1000, 3)}) # 15 + something1
sum5 = sum({*range(5, 1000, 5)}) # 15 + something2

sum3 + sum5 == 15 + 15 + something1 + something2
```

in the second one, you are combining the two set of numbers, so
this `{*range(3, 1000, 3)} | {*range(5, 1000, 5)}` will only contain one copy of 15 and any other multiple of both numbers

```
sum({*range(3, 1000, 3)} | {*range(5, 1000, 5)}) == 15 + somthing_else
```

Answer (score -1):

As @mkrieger1 points out, the other answer has the `|` operator in it, which is the logical OR operator.

If we look at [the problem you want to solve,](https://projecteuler.net/problem=1) it says 3 OR 5, so you want to eliminate the common multiples (like 15), which is why the other person included it.